# Realm RealmCollectionChange get changed property

Tags: swift, realm

I have an "Owner" class that has a list property of dogs

```
class Owner: Object {

    dynamic var name: String?

    let list = List<RString>()

}
```

I added a notification token to the list of `Owner`

```
owners?.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in 

    updateUI()

}
```

The problem is, whenever the properties of `RString` are changed, and one of the owners has the changed `RString` in his list, this notification is triggered

What I want is to ignore changes that happen to RString objects and avoid triggering the notification

Is there a way to add "ignoringProperties" to the `collectionChanges` just like the one in `objectChange`? Or any other workaround?!
 like getting the name of the changed property and ignoring it manually?

I have seen this code in one of Realm official videos but couldn't replicate it for collectionChanges

```
let token2 = state.addNotificationBlock(ignoringProperties: ["noisyProp"],
                                    block: { change in
  // handle change and avoid being notified for properties we don't care about
})
```

[source](https://academy.realm.io/posts/meetup-jp-simard-mastering-realm-notifications/)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.update` case of the [`RealmCollectionChange`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Enums/RealmCollectionChange.html) enum passed into your update notification handler only contains the indexes of any modified objects contained in the `Results` returned from your query. So, as of now, it seems that preventing update notifications from being triggered by specific properties is not possible.

As an alternative, you might consider modeling your data differently by creating a separate `Dog` object and giving it an `ownerId` property and removing the dog `list` property from your owner object. This way you avoid update notifications from being triggered on your `Owner` query results when an owned `Dog` is modified.

Comment: That's what I am doing currently, but when I read the example in the official realm page I thought another way may exist, and couldn't find any example... thanks for your help